# How to include moment.js inside marionette application?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, momentjs

I am a newbie to Marionette and moment.js and as such to javascript and web programming, hence please excuse me if my question sounds stupid.
Here is what I want to achieve.
I want to use moment.js globally in my marionette application, and hence I want to do something like this, but how can I do it?

```
SuperAppManager.module('AppointmentsApp.List', function (List, SuperAppManager, Backbone, Marionette, $, _, moment) {
 var date = moment();

}
```

Regards,
Chidan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, according to [Custom Arguments](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.application.module.md#custom-arguments) from Marionette documentation:

```
SuperAppManager.module('AppointmentsApp.List', function (List, SuperAppManager, Backbone, Marionette, $, _, moment) {

 var date = moment();

}, moment);
```